# Traffic Sign Detection and Recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

What is best method of Traffic Sign Detection and Recognition?
I review the popular traffic sign detection methods prevalent in recent literature, but don't know which way is best!
I would like to use Color-based and shape-based detection methods.

I work image processing using opencv in visual studio c++.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:
https://sites.google.com/site/mcvibot2011sep/

Answer (score 1):

Check [dlib](http://dlib.net/). The file [`example/train_object_detector.cpp`](http://dlib.net/train_object_detector.cpp.html)* has some details on how this can be achieved. It uses a feature description technique called [**Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients).

Check the following links for a starting point:

- [Detecting Road Signs in Mapillary Images with dlib C++](https://gist.github.com/iandees/f773749c47d088705199)
- [Dlib 18.6 released: Make your own object detector!](http://blog.dlib.net/2014/02/dlib-186-released-make-your-own-object.html)

---

* Note: don't just use the examples to train your detector! Read the files as a guide/tutorial! These example programs assume that you are trying to detect faces and make some improvements based on that (such as using image mirrors on training since faces are symmetric, which can be be disastrous for some signs).

---

**Edit: Check my implementation of a traffic sign detector and classifier using dlib:**

https://github.com/fabioperez/transito-cv